# including a variable in an R1C1 formula

Tags: excel, vba

This code retrieves the number of filtered data - RelCov.  It then counts the number of "wands" in that group of RelCov.  The R1C1 formula compares the weeks number of RelCov last week and returns the the differnce as "?more", "?less" or "Same as last week"   I then wnat to append on the end of that formula, the number of "wands" that are RelCov.  Whenever i include & wands in the formula, I get a "NAME" error.  This is what I have:

```
    Windows("usertemp.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim RelCov As Integer
    RelCov = Application.CountIf(Range("ah:ah"), "Relevant Covered")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$18690").AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="Relevant Covered"
    Dim wands As Integer
    wands = Application.CountIf(Range("b:b"), "WAND*")
'    MsgBox wands
    Windows("User File Analysis test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("ReleventCovered").Select
    ActiveCell = RelCov '& Chr(10) & wands & " wands"
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(rc[-1]<r[-1]c[-1],r[-1]c[-1]-rc[-1]&"" less"",if(rc[-1]>r[-1]c[-1],rc[-1]-r[-1]c[-1]&"" More"","" same as last week""))& "" wands = """
```

When I include & wands & after ""Wands = "" at the end of the formula, I get a "Name" error.  How do I include the "wands" variable at the end of the forumula with getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(IF(RC[-1]<R[-1]C[-1],R[-1]C[-1]-RC[-1] &"" less"", IF(RC[-1]>R[-1]C[-1],RC[-1]-R[-1]C[-1]&"" More"","" same as last week"")), "" wands = ""," & RelCov & ")"
```